# Do tools.pingdom.com gives speed results with caching or without caching?

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, w3-total-cache

I am using w3 total cache plugin for my website, after activating plugin my website speed is much faster at my end . But when I check my website speed in tools.pingdom.com it is giving bad speed.So,do tools.pingdom.com gives speed results with caching or without caching?

Answer (score 0):

When you will install the w3 total cache plugin then tools.pingdom.com will show the caching result. you can make try with deactivate plugin and check again on pingdom. 
If you're getting speed or performance problem and need to increase on pingdom as well then check **Performance Grade** tab also click on sort by load time, you will get where is issue and what you need to do.